# How much is Cristiano Ronaldo Salary at Juventus

Tags: football, international-sports

I want to know the transfer of Cristiano Ronaldo from Real Madrid to Juventus and how much is his weekly Pay after tax

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivial number available directly from a variety of sources.

Comment: With all due respect why will you vote me down sir.

Comment: Literal purpose of downvotes: *"**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Several sources (for example [here](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/07/10/cristiano-ronaldo-just-signed-a-deal-with-juventus-worth-over-100-mil.html) or [here](https://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/news/cristiano-ronaldos-juventus-wages-broken-12890306)) reported the deal to be worth 120 Million Euros over four years.

- That's 30 Million Euros per year or 576,923 Euros per week.
- The tax rate for this kind of income in Italy is 43% ([source](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/italy/index_en.htm)).
- 576 grand * 57% = **328,846.11 Euros** per week (100% - 43% taxes = 57% to keep)

Comment: How solid is your source

Comment: @Wealsegun since several press agencies reported this it is pretty solid and as close as you can get. You'll never have a guarantee that those numbers are real, unless you ask Juventus or Ronaldo personally.